# regarding mfc dialog bar

Tags: c++, mfc

I am new to MFC and VC++ programming. I have two questions:

- How do I make a resizable dialog bar?
- How do I give background color for a dockable dialog bar?

Thanks!

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

So i assume we are working in visual studios 2008 or similar and i assume you have an MFC SDI or MDI application that you are working on.

- Open the resource viewer (View->resource view).
- Expand the project that you would like to place the dialog in.
- Expand to the dialog folder.
- Right click this folder and click add resource.
- Expand and add a new dialog bar.
- Give it any properties you like using the properties window.
- To (display/ give context) your dialog bar, instantiate and get the
  handle of the dialog. Like

  `GetDlgItem(ID)-> ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);//show`

Where `ID` is the id of the dialog. You can obtain this by going into the resource viewer, right click on the dialog, properties, and the `ID` is given in there.